# change config/newrelic.yml path

Tags: capistrano, symfony-2.1, newrelic, capifony

I'm using the new relic ruby agent with symfony 2.1 and capifony.

I'd like to be able to tell the new relic agent that the config file lives under app/config/newrelic.yml instead of config/newrelic.yml

Is this possible?

Comment: Just want to clarify that you are trying to use the **Ruby** New Relic agent with the Symphony 2.1 **PHP** Framework?

Comment: @amateurhuman To be exact we use Ruby New Relic agent in deployment of PHP application via Ruby based deployment tool (Capistrano) so it should be ok I would say. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `NRCONFIG` environment variable and you can do it directly in cap call this way:

`cap newrelic:notice_deployment NRCONFIG=app/config/newrelic.yml`

I would like to set it in deployment configuration and according to cap documentation this should work:

`set :default_environment, {
  "NRCONFIG" => "app/config/newrelic.yml"
}`

but it doesn't. ;o(